# Тире или двоеточие в предложении?

Tags: тире, двоеточие, бессоюзное

*Виды тортов (?) шоколадные, ягодные, фруктовые.*

Что нужно поставить в скобках, тире или двоеточие? Вроде можно двоеточие, так как идет пояснение первой части, а вроде и тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас классическое перечисление, перед которым оптимально двоеточие.